# Why is my question getting so many down votes? What am I doing wrong (despite being a newcomer in this community)

Tags: discussion

The question in specific is this one:
[Integrity rules for Document-based DBs from the DDD perspective](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388998/integrity-rules-for-document-based-dbs-from-the-ddd-perspective)

I'm getting down votes with no explanation. And I truly think it's a valid question.

Possible reason and a big problema: I've seen it in other places: newcomers are considered dumb "by default" and tend to get many down votes just because it's written in their avatar that they are newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

In between, your question was closed as "too broad" (and a comment in the same direction), which may have served for you as an explanation?

In [this former meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490), you can find further explanations what the community here considers as "too broad". And don't take those downvotes personal - you did not get downvotes, only your question got.

One reason for this is the community here tries to keep the site clean by self-moderation, and voting for deletion on an off-topic question requires the question to have a score of -3 or lower, that's part of the site's mechanics.

Comment: yes, that last comment as "too broad" was added last, while also closing the question... but before that I was just getting plain downvotes with no explanation...

the first comment came with a downvote already, asking me to explain more.. so I did extend the question and got 3 extra downvotes, before the "too broad" comment/closing.

Comment: @JoãoOtero:  did you notice you still wrote "I got downvotes" instead of "my question got downvotes" ;-)?

Comment: yes, I've noticed... I didn't take it personally though. I've seen already many broad / philosophical questions being asked around, with very good and insightful answers. Sometimes those kinds of questions are rejected (like this time); and in other times they are accepted. I think that instead being rejected, there should be a specific category for "philosophical / opinionated questions". I think those kinds of questions, which doesn't have one specific and particular answer, are also valid and important kinds of questions that deserve answers.

Comment: oh, one more thing: see that the in the title I've mentioned "my question" getting downvotes? the part where I mention "I'm getting" downvotes is because they were happening "without explanation" (the explanation is important to instruct and evolve the questioner)

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask after having read the question. Did this question get downvoted and closed due to bad english?

I can totally imagine the same question being posted with different phrasing:

"Where should data integrity rules be placed in DDD" with maybe some example pseudocode getting answered and upvoted.

It would be a shame if non native english speakers are excluded from contributing questions.

contrast our response with the same question on stack overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127274/mongoose-data-integrity

Comment: Yes, the question you mentioned is part of the same concern (data integrity). But in Stackoverflow I was taking into account a specific technology. While in here I was looking for a more general answer / best practice.